# Filter out minimum area rectangles - Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to get the coordinates of the 4 vertices of minimum area rectangles constructed around some objects of similar characteristics in an image, ignore if they are equal to a certain set of values, and if they are not, add them to a list.

Here is how I get the vertices:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for contour in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour) 
        points = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)    
        points = np.int0(points)  
        coordinate_list.append(points)
```

So `points` contains the coordinates. I tried printing `points` and here are part of the output that is printed in the console:

```
[[459 467]
 [459 467]
 [459 467]
 [459 467]]
[[450 466]
 [450 466]
 [450 466]
 [450 466]]
[[306 376]
 [306 376]
 [306 376]
 [306 376]]
```

This output confuses me as I do not know how to write them in my code.

Now suppose I want to ignore rectangles with vertices of coordinates `((459, 467),(459, 467),(459, 467),(459, 467))` and `((450, 466),(450, 466),(450, 466),(450, 466))`. I tried inserting the following code before the `coordinate_list.append(points)` statement:

```
if points in [[[459 467], [459 467], [459 467], [459 467]], [[450 466], [450 466], [450 466], [450 466]]]:
    continue
```

I also tried a number of ways to display the vertices (like adding commas, replacing square brackets with normal brackets etc) in the hope of matching the correct format that `points` store the values but I can't seem to find the right answer.

How can I write this `if` statement correctly?

P/s: If anyone has a more appropriate title for this question, please help me change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.boxPoints` should return only 4 coordinates which contain the minimum spanning bounding box for the contour.  In your code, what is returned is a `numpy` array of size `4 x 2` where each row is a rectangle coordinate of the minimum spanning bounding box.  The fact that you get repeated coordinates is rather odd.

In any case, since `points` is now a `numpy` array, one way would be to check if the `x` coordinate of the returned box coordinates are in a set of coordinates provided by you and the same for `y`.

As such, something `numpy`-ish would look something like this:

```
# Store x and y coordinates as column vectors
xcoord = np.array([[459, 450]]).T
ycoord = np.array([[467, 466]]).T

# Run contour detection code
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

coordinate_list = []

# Go through each contour...
for contour in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour) 
    points = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)    
    points = np.int0(points) 

    # Check to see if any rectangle points are in our lists
    if np.any(np.logical_and(xcoords == points[:,0], ycoords == points[:,1])):
        continue

    coordinate_list.append(points)
```

What I did first was create separate `numpy` arrays that contain the `x` and `y` coordinates of the coordinates that you don't want to see in the list.  You need to make sure that you put the points in the **correct** order.  Therefore, `xcoords[0]` and `ycoords[0]` belong to one `(x,y)` point.  Similarly, `xcoords[1]` and `ycoords[1]` belong to one `(x,y)` point etc.

Note that I've made the column vectors (`N x 1` arrays) so that I can broadcast easily.  Next, for each contour that we have detected, get the minimum spanning bounding box, then check to see if any of the `x` and `y` coordinates in this minimum spanning bounding box  `xcoords == points[:,0]` checks to see if there are any `x` points in our list that we don't want to include are detected in the set of `x` coordinates in the detected rectangle.  Similar case for `ycoords == points[:,1]` for the `y` coordinates.  Doing `np.logical_and` will now check the pairs of coordinates and see if both `(x,y)` pairs that we defined in `xcoord, ycoord` are seen as coordinates in the detected bounding box.  Doing `np.any` checks to see if any such instance occurs.  If this is `True`, we continue and skip this bounding box.

The output should be stored in `coordinate_list` where the rectangles whose coordinates you wanted to skip over don't appear.

Comment: I guess the repeated coordinates belong to dots that are default to my image, that's why I do not want to include them to `coordinate_list`.

Comment: No problem. In that case, this code should remove those dots!

Comment: Since you said `points` is a `numpy` array, would it make any difference if I convert it to a list and then compare it with my list of points? As I need to get access to these points later, can I check if there is any difference accessing `numpy` array and a normal list?

Comment: You could do that yes. I took advantage of the fact that they are numpy arrays to allow me to use those methods to efficiently determine those points you need to remove.

Comment: Btw, if I'm not wrong, following your algorithm, as long as `points` is a rectangle with at least 1 of the vertices with coordinates same as the pre-defined coordinates of x and y, the rectangle is skipped? So can this algorithm be applied to the case where the rectangles I want to skip have vertices of different coordinates?

Comment: and last question :P when I printed `points2 = points.tolist()` I got something like this `[[163L, 56L], [163L, 56L], [163L, 56L], [163L, 56L]]`. Do you by any chance know what the `L` means? When I printed `points2[1][1] I get `163`, so idk how the `L` just disappear

Comment: L means long. It's an integer type. You don't need to make it disappear. It's an integer!

Comment: Also yes you are correct. If at least one vertex in your rectangle is in the list, it skips.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your responses!!